# Excel: date range with non-unique entries. Only return values of adjacent cell if date is lowest non-unique entry

Tags: excel

In column A, I have a list of non-unique dates. In column B, I have a list of numbers. I am attempting to put together a formula that I can copy down column C that will only return the value in column B if either the date in column A is unique, or where the date is non-unique, the non-unique date sits in the lowest row. Sorry I'm struggling to articulate this better. Hope this and the table below will be enough to help resolve my query.

```
Column A     Column B  Column C
04/05/2001   0.05      0.05
05/06/1996   0.01      0.01
13/11/1991   0.00963   n.a.
13/11/1991   0.004815  0.004815
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In cell C1 and copied down: `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1),B1,"n.a.")`

Comment: Alternate solution, in cell C1 and copied down: `=IF(A2=A1,"n.a.",B1)` assuming dates are sorted

Comment: Thank you ever so much - very kind